# Problema com o compartilhar

Tags: android

Eu usei o seguinte código para capturar um texto e compartilhar.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String texto = "Olá sou um texto compartilhado"
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, texto);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Quando executei a primeira vez ele abriu corretamente o compartilhar contendo todos os aplicativos. Quando eu executo novamente ele vai direto para o aplicativo que eu escolhi na primeira vez. É como se tivesse ficado salvo. Mas eu quero que ele abra sempre o compartilhar para escolher. Como resolver isso ?

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver esse problema deve-se abrir  as opções de compartilhamento para se escolher com qual app quer compartilhar o texto. Dessa forma o código abaixo funciona para o que foi proposto.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String texto = "Olá sou um texto compartilhado";
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, texto);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que está sendo armazenado em cache, pela minha pequena experiência, acredito que isso depende de Android pra Android, pois já vi alguns que somente marcam o ultimo utilizado. Meu app possui quase o mesmo código que você postou, no entanto com algumas pequenas modificações, mas que particularmente nunca vi ocorrer esse problema que mencionaste. Segue:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
String msg = "Sua mensagem aqui"
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Se não resolver, então provavelmente deve ser o seu aparelho, ou melhor, o sistema do seu aparelho. Veja se quando foi selecionar o app pela primeira vez, se foi adicionado como `sempre` nas predefinições, logo, vá nas configurações do app que está iniciando e limpe as predefinições ou padrões (algo do tipo) e teste seu app em outros aparelhos e versões do Android.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu. Ele ainda continua abrindo o mesmo app em vez de abrir as opções de compartilhamento.

Comment: Vou responder com mais algumas considerações